# How to perform a refresh with spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` to authenticate my user with Google. This works well and I can sign in and get valid access and refresh token as expected.

I'm creating the access token as such:

```
public class TokenServiceImpl implements TokenService {

    private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService;

    @Override
    public GoogleCredentials credentials() {
        final var accessToken = getAccessToken();

        return getGoogleCredentials(accessToken);
    }

    private GoogleCredentials getGoogleCredentials(String accessToken) {

        return GoogleCredentials
                .newBuilder()
                .setAccessToken(new AccessToken(accessToken, null))
                .build();
    }

    private String getAccessToken() {
        final var oauthToken = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        return clientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
                oauthToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(),
                oauthToken.getName()).getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
    }
}
```

The token is ultimately being used in the Google Photo API client as such

```
    private PhotosLibraryClient getClient() {
        
        final var settings =
                PhotosLibrarySettings
                        .newBuilder()
                        .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(tokenService.credentials()))
                        .build();

        return PhotosLibraryClient.initialize(settings);
    }
```

The problem is that the token will expire after a short period and I'd like to refresh it to keep it active.

I'm unsure what pattern of methods I can use to do this, without having to write the entire OAuth flow (defeating the purpose of something like the Spring `oauth2-client`).

So far I have no other token/security/filter logic in my application.

Do I just need to write it all out manually, or is there another way I can do this?

Comment: there may be a setting.  You should check the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientService` implementation.  That service you are using just stores the information it looks like.  There may be a higher component that you can use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager** will take care of refreshing your access token for you, assuming you get a refresh token along with your access token.  The doco for OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager is at

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2client

When configuring your OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager, make sure you have included **refreshToken** in the OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider...

```
@Bean
public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
        ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

    OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                    .authorizationCode()
                    .refreshToken()
                    .build();

    DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
            new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                    clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

    // Assuming the `username` and `password` are supplied as `HttpServletRequest` parameters,
    // map the `HttpServletRequest` parameters to `OAuth2AuthorizationContext.getAttributes()`
    authorizedClientManager.setContextAttributesMapper(contextAttributesMapper());

    return authorizedClientManager;
}
```

You then use the OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager to get the access token.  The sample from the spring doco is below...

```
@Controller
public class OAuth2ClientController {

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Authentication authentication,
                        HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
                        HttpServletResponse servletResponse) {

        OAuth2AuthorizeRequest authorizeRequest = OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId("okta")
                .principal(authentication)
                .attributes(attrs -> {
                    attrs.put(HttpServletRequest.class.getName(), servletRequest);
                    attrs.put(HttpServletResponse.class.getName(), servletResponse);
                })
                .build();
        OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = this.authorizedClientManager.authorize(authorizeRequest);

        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = authorizedClient.getAccessToken();

        ...

        return "index";
    }
}
```

If the current accessToken has expired, this will automatically request a new accessToken using the previously obtained refreshToken.