# Jhipster monolith with Vue and Keycloak - Spring session timeout does not logout web ui

Tags: spring, vue.js, oauth-2.0, keycloak, jhipster

I have Jhipster app generated with 8.1.0. Similar question here:
https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/16361

Issue:

- Using the UI works fine, if you leave it idle for 30 min (SSO timeout), the access token becomes invalid, however, the UI keeps working and not redirecting to login. Network tab shows oauth errors, as expected. If you refresh browser page, it goes to login page.

Network tab shows 302 redirect:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/oidc
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

console:

```
refused to connect to 'http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Some links:

- https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/10642
- https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/9684
- https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/24278
- [keycloak - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76564234/keycloak-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-r)
- [How to perform a refresh with spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68899669/how-to-perform-a-refresh-with-spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client)

What I believe is going on here is that we are not actually pointing the browser to keycloak page, which would work and show the keycloak page, but doing an ajax request instead. This must be why we get CORS error and keycloak says no.

---

It seems the jhipster is not handling the spring session timeout properly. After the session timeout, front end makes request to some page, page redirects to login oidc page, which returns 302 to keycloak.

```
cess to fetch at 'http://localhost:9080/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=web_app&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20offline_access&state=P7_kCAbym_dHvQXjfK8MWxl1i30xj5S1eiFwK_ouuAY%3D&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/oidc&nonce=EpqSv3_flBMziTziPCqg2PIK7iOrZMN8JzUyaYnEiYQ' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/api/kafes?page=0&size=20&sort=id,asc') from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
The FetchEvent for "http://localhost:8080/api/kafes?page=0&size=20&sort=id,asc" resulted in a network error response: the promise was rejected.
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ sw.js:18
sw.js:18        Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Until I learn more from jhipster guys, I have an idea how to fix this. Since I must have some kind of session timeout on the UI side, I can show pop up after some time, saying automatic logout. If you click stay on page, I do some request to backend to keep the session alive (refresh endpoint or similar). I was under impression the jhispter would have this all out of the box, so this got me confused. Perhaps they do and I simply do not know how to configure it.